# I want to ping from pc 192.168.1.2 to pc 192.168.2.2 but i am not able to do so. Can someone tell me my mistake

Tags: cisco, routing, network, ping, packet-tracer

[image]

The network is able to ping from pc 192.168.1.2 to router interface 192.168.3.1.

Comment: You've got 192.168.2.2 on a 192.168.3.1 router?

Comment: I have given 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.3.1 to different router interfaces. 192.168.2.1 act as a default gateway for the PC's connected to this router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Both of your routers have the same IP address (192.168.3.1) on the interface connected to Switch 0.

You  must have two different addresses (.1 and .2 for example).

2 - You need a route on each router to tell them where to find the remote network. The most basic way is to add a static route on each

So if the left router has IP 192.68.3.1 and on the right one 192.168.3.2, you need:

on left router

`ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.2`

on right router

`ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1`